# How to use program id as seeds for a PDA

Tags: anchor, pda, anchor-program-idl, crates

[image]I am trying to use my program_id as one of my seeds for a PDA in my code. Here is a sample

```
pub const seed: &str = "seed"

pub struct PoolAccounts<'info> {
  /// CHECK: This is a PDA 
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            seed.as_bytes(),
            crate::ID,
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub pool: UncheckedAccount<'info>, 
}
```

When I build, I get `expected &[u8], found struct anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey`.
However when I add `.as_ref()` to `crate::ID` as expected, the code compiles but I then get a warning `WARNING: unexpected seed category for var: SeedPath("crate :: ID", [])`.

Comment: can you screenshot the picture of the warning?